# Does Kafka Connect provide data provenance?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Iam new to kafka connect. I have used tools like nifi for sometime now. Those tools provide data provenance for auditing and other purpose for understanding what happened to a piece of data. But I couldn't find any similar feature with kafka connect. Does that feature exist for kafka connect? Or is there some way of handling data provenance in kafka connect so as to understand what happened to the data?

Answer (score 0):

A CDC tool may help with your auditing needs, otherwise you will have to build your custom logic using a single message transformation (SMT). For example, using Debezium connector, this is what you will get as message payload for every change event:

```json
{
  "payload": {
    "before": null,
    "after": {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "7b789a503dc96805dc9f3dabbc97073b",
      "last_name": "8428d131d60d785175954712742994fa",
      "email": "68d0a7ccbd412aa4c1304f335b0edee8@example.com"
    },
    "source": {
      "version": "1.1.0.Final",
      "connector": "postgresql",
      "name": "localhost",
      "ts_ms": 1587303655422,
      "snapshot": "true",
      "db": "cdcdb",
      "schema": "cdc",
      "table": "customers",
      "txId": 2476,
      "lsn": 40512632,
      "xmin": null
    },
    "op": "c",
    "ts_ms": 1587303655424,
    "transaction": null
  }
}
```

Comment: So with these would I be able to identify what happened to a piece of data?Let's say I pulled a few rows from a postgres table and it hasn't reached the destination. How will I be able to track that inforamtion with these details? Also I myself pulled data from from mysql using the same connector, but I couldn't find these fields in it, not even the source,is there anything to be added to enable this?

Comment: In addition to the `source` object, you also have `before` and `after` objects and the diff will give you what happened to the data. There is also an `op` field describing the type of operation (c=create,r=read,u=update,d=delete). To track the information you have the source, Debezium log and the destination topic that you can browse with Kafka CLI tools. It's hard to say what's wrong with your configuration without looking at it, but I have and [example here](https://github.com/fvaleri/cdc) that may help.

Comment: Iam not talking about cdc but querying connector like confluent jdbc. Will those things do any good in providing data provenance?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked it. In any case, a CDC tool may help with your auditing needs, otherwise you will have to build your custom logic using a single message transformation (SMT).

Comment: how is generally the data provance implemented in kafka connect? I really stuck trying to understand this.

Comment: @pacman It isn't... You can add interceptors to the Kafka clients like for distributed tracing, but that's not specific to the Connect API